# LINQ instead of for loop in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, linq, richtextbox

I am working with the WPF `RichTextbox`.  I have to get all the lines in the `RichTextbox`.  So I am using a `for` loop to get all the lines, but the `RichTextbox` contains a large text content.  It takes too much time.

So how do I get around a 1000 line loop in less time?

I've tried `parallel.for` but it gives an exception as it tries to get each line of the `RichTextbox` text.

Here is my code.

```
   for (Int32 icnt = 0; icnt <= iLineCount; icnt++)
   {
     LineDetails lnDtls = new LineDetails();
     lnDtls.LineText = GetLineText(txtAppendValue.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(icnt));
     iCurrentEnd = iCurrentEnd + lnDtls.LineText.Length;
     lnDtls.LineLength = iCurrentEnd;
     listLines.Add(lnDtls);
   }
```

GetLineText():

```
   String GetLineText(TextPointer TextPointer)
   {
       tp1 = TextPointer.GetLineStartPosition(0);
       if (tp1 == null)
       {
         return null;
       }
       else
       {
         tpNextLine2 = tp1.GetLineStartPosition(1);
         if (tr != null)
         {
           tr = null;
         }
         if (tpNextLine2 == null)
         {
           tpNextLine2 = txtAppendValue.Document.ContentEnd;
         }
         tr = new TextRange(tp1, tpNextLine2);
         return tr.Text;
       }
   }
```

So can I use LINQ instead of `for` loop for fast execution?

Comment: Abstract LINQ expression isn't faster or slower comparing to abstract `for` loop. If you want to optimize your code, you should tell what's wrong with current implementation.

Comment: @ Dennis : 'iLineCount' value is large like 1000 means,the loop execution time is around 1 to 2 mins.so need to reduce that execution time.How can split that for loop and execute conucurrently or any other way is there for speed execution?

Comment: Using extra threads (including that in `Parallel.For`xxx) won't help because only the UI thread may update the  user interface

Comment: @ MickyD : So how can i resolve it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are accessing the data line by line and not just using RichTextBox1.Text?

Comment: @ Vaelen : have to move line by line navigation.so only.

Comment: Can any one give Equalent LINQ code for above for loop?

Comment: There is no reason at all that retrieving 1000 lines of text, in any context, should take "around 1 to 2 minutes". LINQ or not LINQ has nothing to do with it. You have some horrible performance bottleneck somewhere else. Unfortunately, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it is not feasible to spend time trying to figure out for you where the problem is.

Comment: @ Peter : i have to move nextline and previousline whenever i want to move in that RTB,so i need to get current line number from list and move to nextline/previousline using currentline+1/currentline-1.in each time i wont to get currentcaretposition and some other calculation,so that i get all lines from that richtextbox inj one time.after that i used for line navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it needs to be this complicated. A few simple line of code would give you all the lines in a rich text box.

```
        string text = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
        text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        var lines = text.Split(new char[] {'\n'});
```

Comment: This is providing paragraphs.